# NHibernate seeding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

To successfully start, my application depends one some initial values that need to be present inside a database. In Entity Framework, I can create migration scripts with the fluent API (fluent sql) to initially seed my database on application startup.

Is this also possible with NHibernate? Probably with FluentNHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating your entities manually and write/delete them from the database.

You could also create sql scripts that do this and manually run them by doing something like this:

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (FileStream strm = File.OpenRead("Seed.sql"))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(strm))
        {
            string sqlDelete = reader.ReadToEnd();

            try
            {
                IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlDelete);
                query.ExecuteUpdate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Fatal(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. When writing SQL queries, are they internally transformed to the appropriate dialect?

Comment: I don't believe so.  Although I would think if you created the seed data as Entities instead and managed it like that it would be just as easy as what you are doing from the Entity Framework.  I mean using objects to insert/update/delete your data is the whole point of an ORM.  You are trying to get away from writing raw sql.